# Why mongoid cannot query embedded document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Through large data, I realize it is not supported in Mongoid. For example, I have two model defenition:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :homepage
end

class Homepage
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
end
```

In this example, User and Homepage is a one-to-one relation. In RDBMS, there is a refrence key in homepage table. In mongo, we can embed homepage into user. In this way, we can query users like `User.all`; however, we cannot query homepages exactly like `Homepage.all`.

Maybe *has_one* macro is what I want. I would design some apis for users, such as `/users`; on the other hand, I would also design some apis for homepages, such as `/homepages`. However, if I set `has_one :homepage` in User model, I lose such additions: I cannot query users or homepages according to fields of both User and Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `Homepage` documents from top level, then you need to have their own collection. When we embed a document inside other, it is not stored in a separate collection, rather it is stored in the parent document itself.

So, i think you should have

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :homepage
end

class Homepage
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you will be able to query `Homepage` documents on `user_id` but not other fields of `User`.

Comment: ｅ～at last, I have mentioned the `has_one` macro ~~